# How do I access the full battery status diagnostic in my Lumia 800?

Tags: battery, lumia

I have been using a new Lumia 800 since a week ago, and even after the latest update (firmware version 1600.2487.8107.12070)  the battery lasts less than my old Trophy 7. I have accessed the battery status diagnostic tool as seen on this image:

[image: battery status]

But the "Full Charge Capacity" and "Remaining Charge Capacity" options don't show at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is most likely a HTC application / addition, which is why it's most likely not there on a Nokia which is different hardware (and thus might have a different way of accessing this information if it isn't standardized).

Comment: The photo I have posted is from another Lumia 800 that has the options that my device lacks...

Comment: Unrelated, but interesting: [There is a battery fix for that device](http://mashable.com/2012/03/29/nokia-lumia-800-battery-fix/) Don't upgrade though, read my answer...

Comment: please do not include the make.model as a tag http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/20/should-we-encourage-people-to-tag-their-questions-with-their-handset-model-and-n

Comment: @Joe: There is no consensus there as far as I can see, and note that this question is specific to Nokia Lumia and does not apply to all WP devices. A tag to denote that is essential here...

Comment: @Tom at what point would you consider a consensus being made? The Answers with a positve score say no, The answers with a negative score say yes/sometimes. For the amount of people active on this site and also active on meta I would think it is.

Comment: @TomWijsman Sure, I'll concede for now :)

Comment: @Joe: Your other re-tags seem fine, just found this one a bit odd because it's specific. The tricky thing about meta topics about tags is that sometimes people jump too quickly on doing what is proposed, on Super User someone got a temporary suspension and I wouldn't like to see that happen here. Of course this isn't really a problem so early in the beta, but just note that when the tags contain more questions it would be more feasible for a moderator to set up a synonym and/or delete tags which is a single action for them (and doesn't flood the front page). Keep up the good work, though... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.mobiletechworld.com/2011/12/09/nokia-lumia-800-battery-status-gone-after-firmware-update/) it appears that the latest firmware has messed up the Battery Status icon as well as the application, consider looking for a way to downgrade or attempt to contact Nokia to resolve the issue you are experiencing.

I haven't read it in detail, but perhaps the [battery fix](http://mashable.com/2012/03/29/nokia-lumia-800-battery-fix/) I posted above fixes this (or causes this); in any case, be on your guard when down/upgrading to make sure what it will do.

Comment: The 12070 update also messes up the volume on the phone. Even if you have the volume set to 1/30 it will still ring at full volume for the first few seconds ... not good when listening to music. The 12072 update fixes this, but this has not been widely distributed. The 12070 still gives me the worst battery life I have ever had in a smart phone.